# How to get atlassian bamboo to trigger a build automatically from a post commit hook

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bamboo

Trying to trigger atlassian bamboo 2.7 to do a build after we do commits to our git server.

Apparently I have to hit a certain api url with wget:

> wget --no-check-certificate http://myserver.net/build/updateAndBuild.action?buildKey=ABC-DEF

However this does not work. When i run this command, nothing is returned in the http reply, and i've done the following as i should have:

- Configure the build strategy to triggered build mode
- Set my IP address is the trigger IP address
- Committed and pushed some new code

But it does nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Just to check, have you tried `wget` just from the command line, rather than in the post-commit hook?

Comment: Yes, i was trying from the command line first before going to the hassle of adding it as a hook. I added my PC's IP as the trigger address whilst doing this too.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say anything without looking into server logs. My tip is: go to https://support.atlassian.com/browse/BSP and describe the problem there attaching server logs.

And yes I work for Atlassian :)

Comment: Yeah, I've had to file a support request, because this doesn't seem to do anything for me either. I'm sure they'll get back to me quickly, and I'll try to add an answer here if it's something worth adding. Of course, I have bamboo 4.4.1 which is much newer, but this question showed up when I searched.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation regarding the post commit triggers:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Repository+Triggers+the+Build+when+Changes+are+Committed

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Build+Services

You could try to use the REST Service to see if this works for you: /api/rest/updateAndBuild.action?buildKey=BAM-TRUNK

If this shouldn't resolve your issue, please create a support request as Krystian suggested.

Cheers,
Jens

Comment: Hi, i also tried the /api/rest version with no effect. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix would be to use Git bamboo web hook service.

If you want commits to automatically trigger builds:

**Set up Github**

Go to ur github repository->settings -> Webhooks & Services

Select "Bamboo" from the "Add service" dropdown

Base url: https://(compnayname).atlassian.net/builds

Build key: your Bamboo build plan key (goto plan summary the last part of URL is the build key)

Username: bamboo useranme (with build permissions)

Password: as specified.

**Set up Bamboo**

Add 'builder' to the users who can build the plan (Plan Configuration -> Permissions)

Add a trigger (Plan Configuration -> Triggers)

Description: trigger  description

Repositories: Select the repo that needs to be build automatically

Trigger IP addresses: IP addresses of the repository server (you might try out leaving it blank as bamboo searches the default IP address)

Comment: Where would I find the trigger IP address? What server?